# Start Service after boot

Tags: android, service, boot

How to start service after booting that run the `onCreate()` function on `mainActivity`? i already use `broadcastRecivier`, i can make the service, but i cannot execute the funtion from main activity.

this is my code `broadcastReciver`

```
public class BootStartUpReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Start service on Boot
        if(intent.getAction().equals(intent.getAction())){
        Intent service = new Intent(context,TestService.class);
        service.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(service);
        }
        //Start App on Boot Start up
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        //if(intent.getAction().equals(intent.getAction())){
        Intent app = new Intent(context,TestService.class);
        app.setClass(context,SatuActivity.class);
        app.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(app);
    }

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `startService()` and start an `Activity`.  You would have to call `startActivity()`.  Note that this is not a recommended pattern as most users do not want to see an app every time they boot.

Comment: i have change to start activity but i got some crash, and i cannot look logcat, cause it after reboot

Comment: You can still examine logcat after boot.  The logcat buffer is a circular RAM buffer and is rather large.  So even after the device boots and you see the "This applications has stopped" dialog, you can still connect logcat.  You'll need to look at this to see where your crash is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are starting Activity as a Service.. please change to startActivity()

```
  Intent app = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);// pass main activity
  app.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  this.startActivity(app);
```

Comment: i have change it to start activity and change to my main activty, but i got crash after boot

Comment: can you post your Logcat?

Comment: you can still see the logcat on your Logcat window, it may be large.., bt u can filter with your package, find it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way it works for me :

```
final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(
                    "your.package",
                    "your.package.MainActivity");

i.setComponent(cn);

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i use your code, and when my activity open after i compiled it, it doesnt run the function on main activty

Comment: I misread your question, I don't excatly understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You mean that onCreate of MainActivity is not called whereas MainActivity is started?

Comment: sorry i got missunderstanding about that oncreate mainActivty, the function is running, but when i restart my phone, i got crash after boot

Comment: Do you have required permissions?

android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED